# First guideline to create an app for price list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-play-services

I'm trying to search some guidelines to create my first app for a price list. If I search on Google I find only ready system but I'd like to make something customized. My needs are to import a 3-4000 lines excel sheet for products with different measures and give to customers the possibility to make a quotation with their personal discount and place an order our make only a quotation for logged users. Instead for not logged user to see only product without prices. Then I don't know if it's better to make contents downloadable or to load all contents inside the app. I think it's better to download contents, so I can update prices directly without make them download each time an app update. Then a possibility to show some pop-up with products news, sometimes in a month. I'm yet practice with magento, WordPress and sql queries. I think The best for me is to find some kind of cms, for phone app, if they exist. Cross platform maybe the best. To understand something like wish or geek. I wait for your replies. Thank you guys!

Comment: For the community to help you, you must at least have done something, a show of effort on your side. You can do this in Android, iOS, Xamarin (cross-platform), Phonegap (cross-platform), etc. Just pick a tool and learn how to use it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm just asking for which software starting to study, according to my needs. And you can advice me directly. I tryed to search for a software to make what I need, but google give me always only ready app solution, with month payement. I don't knew Xamarin and Phonegap. It's my first experience with apps. Which crossplatform software is more diffused? And which has a great community behind that can give me help at first time?